# Does Firefox stores keywords in its Google Analytics cookie?

Tags: firefox, search, google-analytics, phrase

I'm trying to extract the keyphrase someone used to land on a website. And since I have the Google Analytics script, I should be able to get the cookie name ___utmz and then look for the string "utmctr=...." to find what keywords.

However, in Firefox, no matter what, I always see (not provided)

```
utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
```

Is there a way to extract the keywords if someone visited using FF?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Google Analytics or Firefox but instead is a result of how keywords are handled for SSL searches with Google. In those cases, Google search will not pass along the keyword in the referral and instead sets the value to (not provided). For details see the keyword section in https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033173